# Find Last Index in column of a specfic Value/Text - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a sorted column that looks something like this:

```
            Cat
            Cat
            Cat
            Cat
            Dog
            Dog
            Dog
            Dog
```

I want to find the last index of cat (which in this case is 4) and the last index of dog (which in this case is 8)

I tried the following:

```
Dim Last_Index_F As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Last_Index_F = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Cat", after:=Range("A2"), searchdirection:=x1Previous).row
End With

MsgBox (Last_Index_F)
```

But I'm getting the first index of Cat coming after A2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would be like this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Last_Index_F As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngF As Range
    Dim strAddress As String, n As Long
    Dim vR()

    Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With rngDB
        Set rngF = .Find("Cat", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If rngF Is Nothing Then
        Else
            strAddress = rngF.Address
            Do
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                vR(n) = rngF.Row
                Set rngF = .FindNext(rngF)
            Loop While strAddress <> rngF.Address
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Max(vR)
    MsgBox vR(n)

End Sub
```

Comment: r = .Cells.Find("Cat", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row   is same.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your "after" to the end of the column you are searching.

In my example I just found the last used row of column A

```
    Dim Last_Index_F As Long


With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Last_Index_F = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Cat", after:=Range("A" & LastRow), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With

MsgBox (Last_Index_F)
```